# how can i get the value of this total from the ajax in this situation

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

i am using a codeigniter. Now i am wondering how to get this total from my controller something like success. Here is my data in network:

[image: total]

now what i want is to get total:0 to be alert with my ajax. how can i get it ? Here is my code in ajax in doing that post:

```
function data_table_report(dateselected){
    $("#dataTables-report").dataTable().fnDestroy();

    table =  $('#dataTables-report').DataTable({ 
      "ajax": {
              "url": "<?php echo site_url('patients_report/dataTable_report/')?>"+dateselected,
              "type": "POST",
          },
          responsive: true,
          bInfo: false,
          dom: 'Bfrtip',
          buttons: [{ extend: 'colvis', columns: ':not(:first-child)'}],
            success: function(total) {
              alert(total);
            }
      });
}
```

i want to alert the total but i can't please help me.

Comment: why can't you? do you get errors?

Comment: Try `total.total`

Comment: @JaromandaX i dont know, i dont have errors but i think i am not doing the right thing or something wrong?

Comment: @JohanP it doesn't alert with total.total

Comment: So it seems your `success` callback never fires because you don't even see an `alert`. Try hooking into the `error` callback

Comment: yeah, i am just trying to put it there, i don't know where to put that success thats why i am asking in that situation :'(

Answer (score 0):

try to use this please!!!

```
      function data_table_report(dateselected){
        $("#dataTables-report").dataTable().fnDestroy();

        table =  $('#dataTables-report').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('patients_report/dataTable_report/')?>"+dateselected,
                "type": "POST",
            },
            responsive: true,
            bInfo: false,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [{ extend: 'colvis', columns: ':not(:first-child)'}],
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.total);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: alert(typeof data) to see what type of the data,or add a breakpoint at alert and watch the variable arguments in browser,then you can find all the params pass into the success function.

Comment: i dont know if i am doing correct in javascript or not?

Comment: am i doing the success function correctly or something wrong?

Comment: ...you haven't given any more useful information,like:errors/success function   whether was executed.I'm not sure what wrong about your code.

Comment: i think this success doesnt executed

Answer (score 0):

Try hooking into `dataSrc` instead of `success` as `success` is used internally by Datatables . https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

```
"dataSrc": function ( json ) {
             alert(json.data.total);
           }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer sir,where would i put it sir ? below or same as where i put the success function

Comment: still doesn't alert

Comment: i already got it. thanks for your link .. the answer is, it must be placed at the top

Comment: opps it destroys my data table also

Comment: You need to `return json.data`

Comment: here , it alerts the total but my data table doesn't work.

Comment: Under the alert, make sure you return json.data. Look at my previous comment.

Comment: Just return json and not json.data. If that doesn't work, then I am out of ideas.